# Connect shipyard with existing docker images?

Tags: docker

I just installed: https://shipyard-project.com/ on my local Ubuntu 17.04 machine. I had already played a bit around with docker before installing Shipyard, e.g. build a `sample` image from a `Dockerfile`:

```
$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
sample              with-jdk8           203484786f91        3 days ago          487MB
sample              latest              39d4758ce1b1        7 days ago          158MB
swarm               latest              0198d9ac25d1        7 days ago          15.8MB
rethinkdb           latest              be24926bde9a        2 weeks ago         183MB
ubuntu              latest              d355ed3537e9        2 weeks ago         119MB
hello-world         latest              1815c82652c0        3 weeks ago         1.84kB
shipyard/shipyard   latest              36fb3dc0907d        9 months ago        58.8MB
microbox/etcd       latest              6aef84b9ec5a        23 months ago       17.9MB
```

Now when I run Shipyard I don't see that image:

[image]

How do I connect Shipyard to my existing images?

Comment: Usually shipyard is used to manage swarm. If you are using shipyard without swarm, we should know more data in order to answer you. What docker run commands did you launched? Is important to know port mapping, etc. Anyway, [here](https://shipyard-project.com/docs/deploy/manual/) is the link to do it with swarm. Did you considered to use [portainer](https://github.com/portainer/portainer) instead of shipyard? I think is prettier and much better. More functionallity.